# API URL's are not working for django app

Tags: python, mysql, django-urls, django-apps, percona

I have hosted a django-python app into server.The app is using mysql as database for app.Unfortunately mysql is upgraded to percona on same server,then after all the django app URL calls are not working.What could be the solution for this problem??

Comment: What specific errors are you getting? Can you post any stacktrace?

Comment: 404 not found
The server can not find the requested page:
http://myappurl (port80)

Comment: This may be more of a server issue than a Django issue. Have you tried restarting your web server? Or looking into your web server logs?

Comment: Yes,I have restarted the server.Still the problem is persisting.